# 800g of peanuts give 700g of peanut butter – why?

Tags: grinding, peanuts, peanut-butter

I’m making my own peanut butter from roasted peanuts that I’m buying. I just got a [wet grinder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zajTf7MzdbA) in order to make a larger amount at the same time.

From the packaging I know that I used 800g of peanuts. But the end result was 692g of peanut butter. I expected it to be the same as what I started with, but am I simply wrong in this assumption? Or does that loss come from leftover peanut butter on the sides and floor, plus the small amount that I tasted during the making?

Comment: @Willeke Good idea! And yeah next time I’ll be able to leave less leftover so we’ll see if that changes it.

Comment: Is this question so bad/irrelevant/offensive that it deserves at least three downvotes?…

Comment: Thanks to the one(s) who restored the votes to 0! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 100 grams of peanut butter will fit into about 6 tablespoons, or slightly under 1/2 cup.  If you tasted, and there was peanut butter left on the sides and floor of wet grinder, that could certainly explain the difference. There is really nowhere else for it to go.

Comment: Hmm I’ll think about it, 100 grams still feels like a lot, but maybe I’m underestimating the amount of peanut butter that I couldn’t get out of the grinder. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Depending on how long you whip it, Water weight also dissappears via moderate evaporation.

Comment: I don’t think there is any water in peanuts though, is there?

Comment: Even a "dried" Peanut has about 5% water by mass. Thou very low, that water content is present. That's why they roast nuts, the drier, the more thirsty you become, that's why bars serve them.
https://wholefoodcatalog.info/nutrient/water/nuts_and_seeds/

Comment: @LazyReader - this doesn't account for 100 g loss from making peanut butter with 800 g peanuts - that's 12.5%. Also at 5% water, there is more water in the atmosphere, so peanuts would absorb water, not lose it.

Comment: Ok, in any case it might be (probably is) a combination of several factors. But I’m using roasted peanuts already, so I’m not sure how much water would be in those.

Comment: @LazyReader The website you linked to actually says how much water there is in roasted peanuts: .3g for 15g, so 2%.